# serving static files under the .next/ folder but different url location

Tags: node.js, next.js

There is a stack that uses Next.js as the main dependency. Each page is an independent application. An index page uses `www.domain.com/_next/*.js` so its base path configured as a `/` root. Also, another application has a base path same as the homepage but a little difference which is using a query string in the URL.

if the URL is `www.domain.com/` then it is a homepage, if the URL is `www.domain.com?key=value` it means it is a different page and the request will be redirected to the associated application by the Nginx and Load Balancers. So, the problem is:

- the main page is serving its statics under the `www.domain.com/_next/*.js`
- the page that parses query strings is serving its statics under the same location same as MainPage `www.domain.com/_next/*.js`

These applications have different statics created by different pipelines also there is a cache mechanism. Is there a way to solve that conflict just by making some configuration in Next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the `basePath` settings introduced in Next.js 9.5 (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath)
  But your .next/ folder would be changed, something like yourdomain.com/yourbasepath/_next
- If you want to change only the `.next/` folder location `assetPrefix` can be used. I think you can take a look at `assetPrefix` https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5602#issuecomment-673382891
- Or we can setup the custom server, for example the Express and custom the base asset path via Express (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

  ```
  app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
  ```

P/s: The asker choose the `assetPrefix` solution

Comment: Sounds good but there is a problem, if I set basePath as `"/newPath"` I am not able to use `www.domain.com?key=value` anymore. Everthing will be served under the "/newPath" so new url wil be `www.domain.com/newPath?key=value`. I am wondering is there way to serve just the `.next` folder under the different location.

Comment: I think you can take a look at `assetPrefix` https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5602#issuecomment-673382891

Comment: that solution is solved the problem. thanks.